# Using an Access Token from Google Sign in for Android to manage a YouTube profile

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, google-signin

I'm building an app that enables the user to login in the app with Google Sign-In and a YouTube scope set, pass the user's access token to a remote server and have the server provide the user with relevant data from the user's YouTube profile, however the Auth Code I get from the Google Sign-In does not work with YouTube.

This is the code I use to get the user's ServerAuthCode (taken from google's guide) on the client.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

     GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE))
            .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
            .build();

     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent signInIntent Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String authCode = acct.getServerAuthCode();
    }
}
```

Then in the server I use the ServerAuthCode and pass it to YouTube and get the data I need, however this doesn't work and I get a 401 response code. I'm pretty sure the code I'm getting from the Google Sign-In is not the code I need to access YouTube. Is there another step I'm missing?

```
            using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient()) {

               webclient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

              webclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);

                webclient.Headers.Add("X-JavaScript-User-Agent", "Google APIs Explorer"); 

                 var respone2 = webclient.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2CtopicDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}");
            }
```

Comment: YOUR_API_KEY are you providing your api key?

Comment: @noev, yes but that key is not the correct key it seems.

Comment: you have to go into google console and create your api key and copy paste that.

Comment: You should use the authCode to get the access token, then use this token to access Youtube API, more info at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/using-credentials-between-your-server.html?m=1

Comment: Where is your OAuth 2.0 access scope. if it is blank, you cannot get access token at all. Actually I am not a java guy, but what I know about youtube api. You cannot get access token, if you not given any scope.

Comment: @cel did you solve this?, I'm getting the same error